# Getting full package name instead of set the String in Google Analytics in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have initialized like this in the Application class

```
  GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        sTacker = analytics.newTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-1");
        sTacker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        sTacker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        sTacker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
```

then I created the common method like

```
  public static void sendScreen(String name){
    if (sTacker != null && Config.ENABLE_ANALYTICS){
        sTacker.setScreenName(name);
        sTacker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }
}
```

Then I called the method in every classes

```
sendScreen("Home Screen");
```

but it's sending the package name as the analytics report.
I have to show the String only which I am passing through the method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi.. I too have the same problem in setting the screen name dynamically. Did u get any solution. If so, please provide it. I can't go for xml option, as i'l be getting the screen name from webservice.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you add this line in your application 
sTacker = analytics.newTracker("");

Just post this line here. 

Or see the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your application class. this should be an google analytics generated xml file. Because it have two more property setting in it

**app_tracker.xml:**

```
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-your ganalyticsid-</string>

 sTacker = analytics.newTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-1");
```

you are just giving tracking id, where autoactivity tracking also need to be enabled.

so it should be

```
  sTacker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
```